# GRUB not cooperating with my new resized partition, throws 'error: no such device'

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

I recently resized my Windows partition on my triple-boot Ubuntu-Windows-RemixOS laptop. However, after shrinking an extended partition and expanding my windows partition with Partition Wizard, GRUB throws this error on every attempted Windows/RemixOS boot up:

```
error: no such device 7C5DBA1B01344B71
setting partition type to 0x7

Press any key to continue...
```

Output in the Terminal of `sudo blkid`

```
    sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL="BOOT" UUID="6447-82CD" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="a7e36a18-01"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Windows" UUID="01D30F3103A00830" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="a7e36a18-02"
/dev/sda4: LABEL="RemixOS" UUID="4E181C45181C2F09" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="a7e36a18-04"
/dev/sda5: UUID="d65808cb-0559-47b6-9749-487546dad39a" TYPE="ext4" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="a7e36a18-05"
/dev/sda6: UUID="09227164-21e4-4661-957e-c157c455b3fb" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="a7e36a18-06"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="F661-8E3D" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="bb83c0db-b009-45f3-8f50-78635cea2eec"
/dev/sdb2: LABEL="Linux" UUID="c5d3050b-68d3-451f-9c35-b58c70c9d6b9" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="2652cd0b-396f-43a7-9265-d65c51f5199c"
/dev/sdb3: UUID="16138385-d7af-4481-aa1f-b66d82428e7e" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="335830c4-6c81-4c2f-b569-bb8b1e752e0e"
```

Output in the Terminal of `sudo fdisk -l`

```
`sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 298.1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xa7e36a18

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048    514047    512000   250M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sda2  *       514048 442339327 441825280 210.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       442341313 572917759 130576447  62.3G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda4       572919808 625141759  52221952  24.9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda5       442341376 563701759 121360384  57.9G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       563703808 572917759   9213952   4.4G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/sdb: 18.7 GiB, 20014718976 bytes, 39091248 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 984BF90B-690C-4D14-8DF5-1D51DA615401

Device        Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1      2048  1050623  1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sdb2   1050624 31084543 30033920 14.3G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb3  31084544 39090175  8005632  3.8G Linux swap`
```

Output in the terminal of `cat /etc/fstab`

```
cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=d65808cb-0559-47b6-9749-487546dad39a /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
#UUID=F661-8E3D  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=09227164-21e4-4661-957e-c157c455b3fb none            swap    sw              0       0
# swap was on /dev/sdb3 during installation
UUID=16138385-d7af-4481-aa1f-b66d82428e7e none            swap    sw              0       0
```

GParted screenshot:

Link since I don't have enough reputation yet: https://ibb.co/dqucUv

This doesn't impede anything, but it's annoying and kind of scary. Any suggestions?

Comment: did you update grub? possible the UUID was changed. Also update initramfs it may be a system map error

Comment: Your mistake was using Partition Wizard, instead of Windows Disk Manager, and gparted. 1. please include the UUID in your question, it's vital to troubleshoot, and it contains no information of any security concern, 2. edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `sudo blkid` and `sudo fdisk -l` and `cat /etc/fstab`, 3. show us a current-window-only screenshot of gparted

Comment: It looks like you have BIOS/MBR on sda, but sdb is UEFI with gpt partitioning. Best not to mix install types, either all UEFI/gpt or all BIOS/MBR. Since sda is BIOS/MBR is that how you have set to boot from UEFI/BIOS? And have you installed Ubuntu's grub to MBR of sda? Total reinstall of all of grub may be required as UUID does not seem to exist.